# how to do this? first div width out ohver and second one with hover,and box shadow?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZPMp.jpg)[enter image description here][2]

how to do this? first div width out ohver and second one with hover,and box shadow?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir8d7iyzrotv58e/Beatles---Copy.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since this question is very *unclear* without the picture and still somewhat unclear with, plus doesn't show any research effort, nor a [mcve], I'm voting to close as *unclear what you're asking*. However, Abdullah, read through the links provided by @Paulie_D and edit your answer accordingly, then you will most likely receive the help you're looking for. Also, please read [ask].

Comment: Plesae show us what you have tried so far. Please also consider doing some research, there are plenty of solutions on "*how to add hover and shadow effects with css*".

Comment: they don,t allow to me upload a pic. for this cause i share dorpbox image link.

Comment: Abdullah, did you read through any of the links provided? If not, please do so. Seriously. It will help you understand Stack Overflow and post questions of better quality. This, in turn, helps everyone else to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #555;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}
.container:hover .content{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
  <div class="content">
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Text text text text text text text text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you are looking for? If you have more questions, pleas ask them in the comments.

Comment: That's not a bad answer at all, but remember that it is somewhat discouraged to post answers to questions that are of low quality (in this case, still pretty unclear). It makes it somewhat harder to encourage people to actually improve their questions (or post high quality questions to begin with). Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @domsson ok, thanks for letting me know :) Should I delete it?

Comment: Up to you. Now that you've put the work into it, I wouldn't. Just something to consider in the future. :)